# Adding and subtracting dataframe rows conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the dataframe below:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3
4  A4  B4  C4  D4
```

I am trying to write something that would essentially say; if column A contains A1, A2, or A4, then add a 'column E' populated by 'xx' in the rows where any of the three variables appear.

Then create a df2 which only contains the flagged rows and a df3 which has the flagged rows and column E subtracted. Resulting in df2:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  xx
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  xx
2  A4  B4  C4  D4  xx
```

and df3:

```
    A   B   C   D  
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  
1  A3  B3  C3  D3
```

Python/pandas beginner here, so any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing:

```py
mask = df["A"].isin(["A1", "A2", "A4"])

df_a = df[mask].copy()
df_a["E"] = "xx"

df_b = df[~mask]  # add .copy()

print(df_a)
print(df_b)
```

Prints:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  xx
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  xx
4  A4  B4  C4  D4  xx

    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
3  A3  B3  C3  D3
```